# Rails generate incorrect asset path with set 'config.assets.compile = false'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I generate a new rails application, and run it in production, but the assets path generate incorrect. Please notice the follow picture.

[image]

And even though set `config.assets.prefix = '/assets'` not work too

I am using rails 4.2.4 and there is the demo project on [github](https://github.com/TangMonk/rails_asset_bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` manually if the `config.assets.compile` is set to false.